# create dynamic element with php dom

Tags: php, mysql, dom, dynamic, element

i want to create dynamic elements with php dom. means, 
i have several value for an ID in my database, so for each of it i want to create an element and add it to its parent.

for better understanding,

```
table1
1- a
2- b
3- b

<categoies> 
<label1>a</label1> 
<label2>b</label2> 
<label3>c</label3> </categories>
```

i can do manually, but because labels might occur hundred times, i have to get it done by a for loop or alike..

thank you in advance..

Comment: Well, i guess there is no question at all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 
No one knows when the solution appear for a given problem (or i am kidding myself?)

I did

```
//create parent element
$par=$domDocument ....
while($row=mysql_fetch_array(sql))
```

`{ //create child element }`

sorry for any inconvenience